# Where did this usage of "something" originate: "I need a nap something terrible"?

Tags: etymology, idioms, colloquialisms

> I need a nap something awful!

I know what this means, but I could never understand it: it's not easier to say, it's not more efficient, and it doesn't make sense!  When was it started (and why)?

Comment: Heh, I could probably give some solid hunches but I don't think there is anything awesomely special happening here. _Something_ is just a placeholder and has the same rough purpose as "some kind of".

Comment: "I need a nap sort of awfully"?  I think "something awful" has more force than "sort of awfully", or "some kind of awful".

Comment: Another variant of this is "something fierce" instead of "something awful".

Answer (score 2):

According to Harold Wentworth & Stuart Flexner, *Dictionary of American Slang* (1960), this usage of "something" in the United States goes back only to the early twentieth century:

> **something** *adv.* Exceedingly. 1914 "He just cusses her out something fierce." S[inclair] Lewis, *Our Mr. Wrenn*, 1914.

Harold Wentworth, *American Dialect Dictionary* (1944) reports variants from roughly the same period using the regionalism *suthin*:

> **1914 Maine, n.N.H.** Current. 'He come a-skivin', suthin' des'prit!' = extremely strong hard, swift. ... **1926 s.w.Mo.–n.w.Ark. Ozarks.** Th' baby hed th' pukes suthin turrible.

A far from thorough Google Books search finds numerous examples from the first decade of the twentieth century. From J.W. Moody, "[My Quandary](http://books.google.com/books?id=ZR9aAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA5-PA34&dq=%22something+fierce%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6NMGVM28BK_liwKnv4GYCQ&ved=0CEkQ6AEwCDhk#v=onepage&q=%22something%20fierce%22&f=false)," in *The Wood-worker* (August 1903):

> We resawed a few pieces of 1x8 mahogany, when the saw began to dodge or lead to the left. As the machine was vibrating **something fierce**, I shut it off and explained that we must have a solid foundation under the machine.

From E.S. Johnson, "[The Age Limit](http://books.google.com/books?id=1cs1AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA543&dq=%22something+awful%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=TdkGVJymKOX5iwLA3IAQ&ved=0CEQQ6AEwBzhk#v=onepage&q=%22something%20awful%22&f=false)," in *The Atlantic Monthly* (April 1904):

> 'I have served them faithful now for forty year, good times and calamities an' all, an' now they put me to shame! ' Then he sighed **something awful**.
>
> ...
>
> The new boss, he went down with a  gang of six men an' did n't dare to go away from the foot of the shaft, 'cause they heard the pillars goin' *whit-wheet*, chippin' **something awful**, an' chunks o' top-rock settin' the fans goin all they could stand, to get up some o' the gas outen the workin's.
>
> ...
>
> There was three men on, two o' them burned **something awful** to look at.

From Dorothy Richardson, [*The Long Day: The Story of a New York Working Girl*](http://books.google.com/books?id=nc9v3R_BEcMC&pg=PA217&dq=%22something+fierce%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-9EGVKGUMIq5iwKayoHIBg&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAzgK#v=onepage&q=%22something%20fierce%22&f=false) (1905):

> "Oh, they just up and at each other like two cats, tumbling over a stack of them there white velvet necklace-cases, and bloodying up each other's faces **something fierce** ; and then Miss Gibbs she called Izzy ; and Izzy he fired them on the spot."

From Edith Nesbit, [*The Incomplete Amorist*](http://books.google.com/books?id=ceYOAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA88&dq=%22miss+her+something+dreadful%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=890GVIrAAcq8jALshICYDg&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22miss%20her%20something%20dreadful%22&f=false) (1906):

> "I hope you said as how we should miss her **something dreadful**," said Mrs. James anxiously, "Have another cup."

From "[A Crack-a-Jack New Year's Resolution](http://books.google.com/books?id=DZQxAQAAMAAJ&pg=PP32&dq=%22something+fierce%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=NNwGVM3KJuLTiwLU5oCIBQ&ved=0CEgQ6AEwCDgU#v=onepage&q=%22something%20fierce%22&f=false)," in *Trade: A Journal for Retail Merchants* (January 8, 1908):

> Oh, they loaded him up clear to the ears. How by saying a few magic words or something like that they could make hogs multiply **something fierce**, and how there was a hungry market for all that could be raised at a price per pound that would make the first year's profits $8,462.66!

From O. Henry, "[The Count and the Wedding Guest](http://books.google.com/books?id=0Ck-AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA213&dq=%22something+awful%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=l9gGVOD5MMO1igL42oG4AQ&ved=0CD8Q6AEwBjha#v=onepage&q=%22something%20awful%22&f=false)," in *The Trimmed Lamp, and Other Stories of the Four Million* (1909):

> Papa's very proud, and when Fernando wanted to give me several thousand dollars for my trousseau he called him down **something awful**. He wouldn't even let me take a ring or any presents from him.

Answer (score 0):

In *The Tempest* (3.1) Miranda says

> ... But I prattle 
>   something too wildly, and my father's precepts 
>   I therein do forget.

This use of "something" seems to be softening the "wildly" - as in "a bit too wildly" rather than "incredibly wildly". That makes sense for the usual meaning of "something" being vague or undefined. Generally, "something awful" could mean "awful, in a way I can't quite describe."

But in your example, "something" is an intensifier - which is the complete opposite. It feels almost like the "something" is euphemistically substituting for a much stronger intensifier, like

> I need a damn nap!

and the vagueness is helping you avoid saying anything too rude.

Comment: I am not sure that the vagueness is related to avoiding to say something rude.